# Aws elastic beanstalk cambia formato de fecha

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, aws, ec2

tengo un problema con una aplicación Api hecha en asp.net core 3 y en aws elastic beanstalk,
tengo una base de datos Mysql, en algunas tablas de la base de datos guardo unos datos en formato Date, cuando pasa por la api lo convierte en una cadena de texto con el método ToShortDateString(), en local funciona bien y devolvía lo siguiente:

```
{
 "estado": true,
 "data": "28-09-2020",
 "mensaje": "Get correcto"
}
```

Hasta hace unos días funcionaba bien cuando lo desplegaba en aws, sin embargo de la nada se empezó a cambiar el formato al siguiente:

```
{
    "estado": true,
    "data": "9/28/2020",
    "mensaje": "Get correcto"
}
```

No se porqué se cambió el formato de la nada, necesito ayuda, gracias.

Comment: De la nada no, algo se ha modificado, presumiblemente en la configuración de mysql y por eso las fechas las devuelve en un formato diferente

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, al revisar la base de datos todo se encuentra normal, no he modificado el formato del tipo de datos Date, creo que incluso en mysql no se puede.

Comment: puede ser el idioma, por que el formato que te arroja es el de US.